# SQL DB2 Bulk update from csv

Tags: sql, csv, db2, sql-update

I get emailed an excel spreadsheet with 4 columns. The first column is (ID) and the 4th is the (Model#). Is there a way in DB2 to bulk update?

Something like

```
 Update (Table) 
 set Model# = (Model#)
 where ID = (ID)
```

DB2 has Import, but not quite what I'm looking for.

```
 IMPORT FROM my_file.csv
 OF del
 METHOD P(2, 3, 5)
 INSERT INTO my_table(my_column_2, my_column_3, my_column_5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4Did you read the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) for the IMPORT command?

You can use INSERT_UPDATE to update rows where the primary key value matches the data in the CSV file:

```
IMPORT FROM my_file.csv
OF del
METHOD P(1, 4)
INSERT_UPDATE INTO my_table(my_column_1, my_column_4)
```

This assumes that my_column_1 is the primary key in the table…